# Repository has no origin in Git Extensions

Tags: git, bitbucket, git-extensions

I had a repository locally which I eventually managed to push to BitBucket through GitExtensions.
I can check my source code in my account on the BitBucket website.

I had three checkins when I initially committed, all within an hour of each other.

Now, three days later, I've attempted to push another change, and found that pushing to the URL (https) that I originally did, doesn't work. I get an error saying that authentication failed.

Looking at my repository, I notice that there is no origin setup.

Using `git branch -a` I only see 'master'... nothing to do with origin.

How can I appropriately set the origin for this repository, and be able to successfully push and pull changes in GitExtensions?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to look for git origin url, you need to use

```
git remote -v
```

It will show something like:

```
origin  git://github.com/saltstack/salt.git (fetch)
origin  git://github.com/saltstack/salt.git (push)
```

Comment: In GitExtensions you can also [Manage Remote Repositories](https://git-extensions-documentation.readthedocs.org/en/latest/remote_feature.html#manage-remote-repositories)